# Show that for any neighborhood, derivative is not always positive

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

I need to show that for
$\,{\rm f}\left(\, x\,\right)\equiv x + x^{2}\sin\left(\, 1/x\,\right)$ when $x$ is not zero and $\,{\rm f}\left(\, 0\,\right) = 0$,
that there is no neighborhood of $x=0$ where $\,{\rm f}$ is increasing.

I'm trying to use the derivative properties but I need a hint.

Comment: Have you written down $df/dx$?

Comment: yes, but it is f(x) = 1 + 4xsin(1/x) - 2cos(1/x). I even graphed it but I can't find the roots

Comment: No, $f′(x)=1−\cos(1/x)+2x\sin(1/x)$. Find the roots of this equation is tricky, but you can certainly find $x$ in every neighborhood of $0$ for which $f′(x)$ are positive and negative.

Comment: @SimonS What about that $x^2$ term in front of that negative cosine term?

Comment: @imranfat the $x^2$ cancels with the $-1/x^2$ which pops up from the derivative of $\sin(1/x)$ when you apply the Chain rule

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko. Yep, got it now....Thanks

Comment: it has something to do with $\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{1-\cos(t)}{t^2}=\dfrac12$ and $\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{\sin(t)}t=1$, that is $1-\cos(t)$ goes to $0$ faster that $\sin(t)$ does, as $t\to 0$.